# Separating column value into a new field in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, data-science

I have a df such as below,

```
       Date                Time 
2019-07-23 21:17:47.599  22:00:00.000
2019-07-23 21:11:46.973  21:50:00.000
```

I am trying something like:

```
pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df3.Time)-pd.to_timedelta(df3.Date).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')
```

But I am getting an error of

```
ValueError: only leading negative signs are allowed
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong? I just want the output to be the value in minutes whether positive or negative

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))-pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)
0   19:17:47
1   18:11:46
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: not sure what I am missing but have updated the original post